# Find Focal Length with DLT Algorithm, Matlab Paper Implementation

Tags: rotation, computer-vision, camera-calibration, projective-geometry

I'm trying to implement this paper in matlab:

[Geometry-Based Camera Calibration Using Five-Point Correspondences From a Single Image](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7523997/)

Now, I think I have correctly found the camera position, while I'm still doubtful on the Rotation Matrix and can't understand how to apply DLT algorithm to find the focal length.
I don't understand how to implement the algorithm.
Since focal length is just a parameter, and all other parameters are known, hw the DLT matrix should be formed?

Here is my code, with the images I used.

[Code from GitHub](https://github.com/Brokenp17/Geometry_Camera_calibration_5Points)

If someone could look into it, or suggest a way to use DLT it will be appreciated.
To make it work I found the focal length as if equation [5] and [6] of the paper form a linear system.